# Feature selection and 10-fold cross validation

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, hyperparameter

I am analyzing a case/control dataset with a low number of observations (250) and 45 parameters. I have performed lasso regularization and 10-fold cross-validation. I believe I need to run the CV (x) number of times to tune my hyperparameter (lambda) but uncertain how many times this would be. Would I use the average of lambda over (x) amount of times? My ROC AUC would be biased because I used the same data to train/test, correct?

Edit -- Response to @Henry

I am currently using 100 lambdas. If I understand you correctly I should slowly increase my # lambda's so that when I cross-validate, the lambda min and # of parameters do not change (or only slightly).
Example code ->

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
install.packages('clogitL1')
library(Rcpp)
library(clogitL1)
set.seed(145)
# data parameters
K = 10 # number of strata
n = 5 # number in strata
m = 2 # cases per stratum
p = 20 # predictors
# generate data
y = rep(c(rep(1, m), rep(0, n-m)), K)
X = matrix (rnorm(K*n*p, 0, 1), ncol = p) # pure noise
strata = sort(rep(1:K, n))
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
# fit the conditional logistic model
clObj = clogitL1(y=y, x=X, strata, numLambda=100, 
                 minLambdaRatio = .0000001, switch = 0, alpha = 1))
plot(clObj, logX=TRUE)
# cross validation
clcvObj = cv.clogitL1(clObj)
plot(clcvObj)
summary(clcvObj)
```

Would I summarize the accuracy of the model with a ROC curve?

Comment: It is not clear to me that you are doing any testing, but instead doing cross-validation.  You want to do this with a wide enough range of $\lambda$s with a fine enough graduation to spot a good choice of $\lambda$.  Here "enough" is a weasel word, so I would suggest you start with a few values of $\lambda$ starting very small and ending very large so you can identify where it is worth looking in more detail.  Once you are getting similar values of your criterion for different values of $\lambda$, then you have probably done enough.

Comment: @Henry , thank you, I have updated the question with more details.